# meaning of つけて in 助走つけてやるもんじゃない

Tags: grammar

I know that ~てやる is to do something for someone.

I also know that やるもんじゃない means "shouldn't do"

I have a feeling I should ignore ~てやる because て is a part of つけて.

However, I don't know what つけて is supposed to mean after 助走

Anyway, for context, I'm reading about a guy asking a girl to stretch. He says:

> じゃあ背中押してもらえるかな
>
> 助走つけてやるもんじゃないから柔軟は
>
> 体硬くてごめんね

I'm mostly confused what つけて's role is and how the rest of やるもんじゃない combines with it.

Not to mention the word 助走 doesn't seem to have a good translation to English?

I'm having a tough time deconstructing the meaning behind all the parts

Comment: 助走 originally means (e.g.) the approach in long jump (you run then (step and) jump). By extension, it means an action to get an momentum. In this case, I suppose the speaker swings herself back to stretch herself further forward (than is possible without swing back). And the interlocutor is suggesting that's not how stretching should be done.

Comment: As explained by the OP, it's a monologue

Answer (score 2):

助走つける take a run up

助走つけてやるもの something you take a run up for

助走つけてやるもんじゃない not something you need to take a run up for

つける means to “add” the run up for whatever it is you’re taking the run up for

In this case it seems to be that he’s asking someone to help stretch by pushing his back. They put too much effort in so he says “you don’t need a run up for stretching”

Look on YouTube for examples of 助走

Comment: What does "run up" mean? They're talking about stretching.

https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E8%B5%B0

This website says it has a second meaning. "To prepare for something before it happens". How does that fit in the sentence?

Comment: I got it! He’s complaining that the person helping with the stretch is taking a run up. Sorry about that. Let me edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

助走 literally means a run-up or a running start in sports. 助走をつける is a more or less fixed collocation. I think the use of the verb つける is influenced by 勢いをつける. In its figurative sense 助走をつける is practically interchangeable with 勢いをつける, meaning to get a momentum before you do something.

やる is a colloquial version of する, not of あげる, in this context.

Your sentence would be translated to something like:

> Stretching (or helping someone do it) is not something you do with a running start, you know.

If the girl said this, she must have thought the guy was asking her to push his back forcefully and reminded him that that's not how he should be stretching his body.

Comment: Only the guy was talking the whole time but thanks for the girl perspective too

Comment: @Tek - Then the guy complained she was pushing him too hard.

Comment: @aguijonazo exactly. A full translation: “Do you think you could give my back a push? Hey, you don’t need to take a run up to stretch! Sorry my body’s so stiff”. The guy is talking to the girl the whole time